# Create dataframe of all rows AFTER varying amount of header data Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframes with a varying amount of header data.
I need to remove the header data, (ie. create a new dataframe containing only the data that comes after this header)

I have used the following code to find the row where the header data ends.

```
df = xlsx_file.parse('ActualSheet',header= None)    
value_list = ['var1','var2']
df_Header = df[df[0].isin(value_list) & (df[1].isin(value_list))]
```

The above code works and creates a dataframe of the final row of header data.

I am having trouble creating a new dataframe from the original data that only includes the rows **AFTER** this "df_Header" row.

Any help is appreciated, I know the answer is already out there but I could not find it.

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so one could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: got my answer already. Will do next time I have a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
df = df[df_Header.index.max():]
```

or

```
df = df[~(df[0].isin(value_list) & (df[1].isin(value_list)))]
```

PS you may also want to make use of `header` and / or `skiprows` parameters of the [read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function

Comment: Thanks! so simple. The first way worked for me. the second way did not. because it only removed the True, I didnt want any rows before the true statement. Anyway Thanks again!